# How to access Azure Storage Table using REST API (ARM)

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

By looking following link it's not clear what the signature should contain or how to form the canonical string to create signature which can be encrypted using HMAC-SH256 alogrithm.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx

I am using following URL

GET https://mystorageaccount.table.core.windows.net/Tables

Headers:

```
Authorization   SharedKeyLite mystorrageaccount:<<encrypted signature>>
x-ms-date   Thu 28 Jul 2016 11:19:33 GMT
```

Getting following error:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: Did you try with one of the client SDKs available? It would probably be easier, unless you haven't one for your language/environment.

Comment: I am using REST API with Java. I think the Java SDK doesn't support to get data from ARM Storage table. Only supports Classic Storage.

Comment: There's no difference between fetching data from a Classic or ARM storage accounts. You can use Java SDK. All you need is account name and key to get the data. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. It seems able to fetch the data using Java SDK. 
Still wondering how to generate signature required for REST API.

Comment: @Gaurav, even sdk needs storage key. Is there any way to retrieve storage key using api?

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve the storage key using API. You can use Azure Resource Manager API for Storage to fetch the keys programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

@Prit, Please see the code below for generating the shared key lite of table storage as reference.

```
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String secret = "<storage-account-key>";
// Date for string to sign
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
// canonicalizedResource, such as "/testaccount1/Tables"
String canonicalizedResource = "<Canonicalized-Resource>";
String stringToSign = date + "\n" + canonicalizedResource;
System.out.println(stringToSign);
// HMAC-SHA@%^
Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256HMAC.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes()));
System.out.println(hash);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for the code. My problem is regarding content of '<Canonicalized-Resource>'. I tried various combinations to create <Canonicalized-Resource> but the generated key is not able to authenticate and always giving the same error mentioned above in question.